# Repast: Query() method runs greatly slower than manual iteration

Tags: repast-simphony

Recently I found a big problem using repast query() method. I found it is somehow significantly slower than using the simple manual iteration approach to get the specific agent set. Take a package object query for all hubs with the same "hub_code" for example, I tested both using query and manual iteration approaches:

```
public void arrival_QueryApproach() {
    
    try {
        if (this.getArr_time() == this.getGs().getTick()) {
            Query<Object> hub_query = new PropertyEquals<Object>(context, "hub_code", this.getSrc());
            for (Object o: hub_query.query()) {
                if (o instanceof Hub) {
                    ((Hub)o).getDepature_queue().add(this);
                    this.setStatus(3);
                    this.setCurrent_hub(this.getSrc());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No hub identified: " + this.getSrc());
    }
}


public void arrival_ManualApproach() {
    
    try {
        if (this.getArr_time() == this.getGs().getTick()) {
            for (Hub o: gs.getHub_list()) {
                if (o.getHub_code().equals(this.getSrc())) {
                    ((Hub)o).getDepature_queue().add(this);
                    this.setStatus(3);
                    this.setCurrent_hub(this.getSrc());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No hub identified: " + this.getSrc());
    }
}
```

The executing speed is dramatically different. There are 50000 package and 350 hub objects in my model. It took me on average 1 minute and 40 seconds to run 1600 ticks when using built-in query function, while it takes only 5 seconds when using manual iteration approach. What are the causes to this dramatic difference and why query works so slow? Instead it should logically runs much quicker.

Another issue assocaited with the query methods is that “PropertyGreaterThanEquals” or "PropertyLessThanEquals" runs much slower than using the method “PropertyEquals”. below is another simple example about query a suitable dock for a truck to unload goods.

```
    public void match_dock() {
 
//      Query<Object> pre_fit = new PropertyGreaterThanEquals(context,  "unload_speed", 240);
//      Query<Object> pre_fit = new PropertyLessThanEquals(context,  "unload_speed", 240);
        Query<Object> pre_fit = new PropertyEquals(context,  "unload_speed", 240);
 
        for (Object o : pre_fit.query()) {
            if (o instanceof Dock) {
            System.out.println("this dock's id is: " + ((Dock)o).getId());
            }
        }
}
```

There are only 3 docks and 17 truck objects in the model. it took less than one second to run total of 1920 ticks if using "PropertyEquals"; however, it took me more than 1 minute to run total of 1920 ticks if choosing the query methods “PropertyGreaterThanEquals” or "PropertyLessThanEquals". in this sense, I have to again loop through the all objects(docks) and doing the greater than query manually? This appears to be another issue much affecting the model execution speed?

I am using java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
My Eclipse complier level is 10. Installed JREs (default) JDK 11.

Thanks for helpful advice.